# XRLabel.Angle at Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

iam using DevExpress v.10.2 and want to show a XRLabel on XtraReport with Angle. If iam using the Designer it is working fine. But now i want to do this at runtime, because the Label.Text is dynamic. My Problem is that the Report doesnt show my Label. I read some DevExpress Support article, which descripe that it is just working on PDF-Format. But in my case i just see a small grey line. 
I tried following to just populating my XRLabel for the first:

```
XRLabel druckinfo = new XRLabel();
druckinfo.Text = string.Format("SB{0} {1} EMAIL {2}", _Sachbearbeiter.Sbnr, _Kennung,
                _Sachbearbeiter.Email1); //The values are filled and working.
                druckinfo.Visible = true;
                druckinfo.AutoWidth = false;
                druckinfo.Angle = 90;
                druckinfo.Font = new Font("Arial", 6f);
                band.Controls.Add(druckinfo); //This is the DetailBand where i add other Labels too and its working fine.
                druckinfo.HeightF = 500f; //Setting Height very high, because the text turns and i thought this is working. But seems to have no effect :(
                druckinfo.LocationF = new PointF(400f, 400f);
                druckinfo.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All;
```

If i delete following line:

```
druckinfo.Angle = 90;
```

the Label becomes show fine but without Angle for sure.

Here a Screenshot which shows the Label with top settings on the PDF:

[image]
This are the settings of my Report:

```
 _Report.PaperKind = PaperKind.A4;
 _Report.ReportUnit = ReportUnit.HundredthsOfAnInch;
 _Report.ShowPrintMarginsWarning = false;
 _Report.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

All other Properties are on default value. The Bands which exists are following:

PageHeaderBand
DetailBand
PageFooterBand

regards

Comment: At first glance, your code looks correct. Could you share the entire Report definition (bands, etc.)? Possible this issue is involved by some configuration specific.

Comment: I copied the code from designer now and bring it step to step near my wishes. It works :)

Comment: You can post a new Answer and accept it in order to close this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be working :) I am not sure why this works and my top post dont. But i copied the code which is generated by designer and now it works.

```
XRLabel druckinfo = new XRLabel();
druckinfo.Angle = 90F;
druckinfo.Padding = new PaddingInfo(2, 2, 0, 0, 96F);
druckinfo.SizeF = new SizeF(29.16666F, 500F);
druckinfo.Font = new Font("Arial",8f);
druckinfo.Text = text;
_Band.Controls.Add(druckinfo);
druckinfo.LocationF = new PointF(0F, 500F);
```